# Using EPPLUS how to format cell which contains number to be Text

Tags: vb.net, excel, formatting, epplus

How can someone format the cell which contains a number to be text?
I have my code which is:

```
xlsWorkSheet.Cells(x+2,x+2).style.numberformat.format="@"
xlsWorkSheet.Cells(x+2,x+2).Value = xmlrequstmsg.toString
```

but for some reason even the excel is produced with format Custom and as soon as I double click the cell only then it transforms to the appropriate format.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Its because you are calling `ToString`.  The `Value` property of the cell object from Epplus is  `Object` type so it will allow you to store any type you would like.  If you call `ToString` it will store what `xmlrequestmsg` is as its string representation.  If it is, say, an `int` it will save it as a `string` that looks like an `int` which excel will flag with the green triangle in the corner of the cell (assuming the user has not turned off the warning messages).

So store or cast as a proper numeric format and it should solve the problem.  See if this thread helps: [Using EPPlus how can I generate a spreadsheet where numbers are numbers not text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537981/using-epplus-how-can-i-generate-a-spreadsheet-where-numbers-are-numbers-not-text/31551083#31551083).