# EPPlus - How to set data type of a column to General

Tags: asp.net-core, export-to-excel, epplus

In my `ASP.NET Core 1.1` app I'm using [EPPlus.Core](https://github.com/VahidN/EPPlus.Core) to export data to Excel. Some columns exported have mostly numbers but rarely a text (e.g. `N/A`). These columns in generated Excel are showing (as expected) a `green triangle` on the top left corner of their cells. I want to get rid of those warnings.

**Question**: What's a good way of getting rid of those triangles when Excel is generated? I tried setting the format of these columns to text as follows but it did not work. I guess we need to set the format of these columns to `General` but I can't figure out how:

```
workSheet.Cells["D1:P1"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "General";
```

**UPDATE**:

Per a user's request, the code looks similar to following.

1. Error at inner loop `for (var j = 4; j < testlist[i].Count(); j++){...}`: MyViewModel does not contain a definition of Count()
2. Error at line `if (testlist[i][j] is string){...}`: cannot apply indexing with [] to an extension of type MyViewModel

**Controller**:

```
....
....
var testlist = (qry to load a MyViewModel).ToList();

using (ExcelPackage pkg= new ExcelPackage())
{
     var ws = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("TestWorkSheet");
     ws.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(rc_excel, true);   

    //I'm starting from 2nd row and 5th column
     for (var i = 1; i < testlist.Count; i++)
     {
        for (var j = 4; j < testlist[i].Count(); j++)
        {
          if (testlist[i][j] is string)
          {
             ....
             ....
          }
    }
  pkg.Save();

  return(....);
}
```

Comment: If those values are strings of number (i.e. numbers stored as text) excel is going to complain by design.  You can disable the warning, probably not ideal though.  Better to actually store the strings as numbers (assuming they are):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537981/using-epplus-how-can-i-generate-a-spreadsheet-where-numbers-are-numbers-not-text/31551083#31551083

Comment: @Ernie That in fact is the issue as described in the post. Most values are numbers but a very few are text (e.g. `N/A`). Disabling the warnings is also not an option as that would imply asking everyone to change their Excel settings - something users would not like.

Comment: So why not just do the conversion based on their value type as shown in that post?

Comment: @Ernie Ok, let me try your suggestion. In my case the `string vs. number` warnings starts from column `5th` onward. So, in my case where should I start the `i` and/or `j` values in the loop of your example?

Comment: The `i` and `j` are basically row,column and you will want to account for the indexes being 1-based in excel.  So your first cell would be [0,4] if you want to start on the top row.  If you have a single header row then [1,4], then added +1 to each value when doing `.Cells[r,c]`.Something like that.

Comment: @Ernie My list is a `List<ViewModel>` and I get it through `(query to load ViewModel).ToList()`. So in your example's **inner for loop** `for (var j = 0; j < list[i].Count(); j++)`, `VS2015` is not recognizing Count() method. It's  complaining your `ViewModel does not contain a definition of Count()`

Comment: Update your question with the code you have so far.

Comment: @Ernie I've added an UPDATE section to my post. There are basically two errors that I've to overcome. Otherwise, it should work.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and find out what `(qry to load a MyViewModel)` returns. Seems like it is not an `IEnumerable`.  Whatever it is, you need to be able to get it to an array or collection in order to loop.

Comment: @Ernie User `@Dmitry`'s response to my [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44377206/1232087) and your [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31551083/1232087) did the trick. Thank you for giving me a start.