# Issue on looping over a list of ViewModel using for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In the following controller, I need to loop through each element of a List. MyVieModel has quite a number of attrubutes (columns) and the list has thousands of rows. So, for brevity I need to use an outer and an inner loop. But, the `VS2015` is complaining at the following lines in the controller. How can I resolve the issue?

1. **Error** at inner loop `for (var j = 0; j < testlist[i].Count(); j++){...}`: `MyViewModel` does not contain a definition of Count()
2. **Error** at line `if (testlist[i][j] ....){...}`: cannot apply indexing with [] to an extension of type MyViewModel

**ViewModel**:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public float laborCost { get; set; }
    public float ManufCost { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    ....
    ....
}
```

**Controller**:

```
....
....
var testlist = (qry to load MyViewModel).ToList();

for (var i = 0; i < testlist.Count; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < testlist[i].Count(); j++)
    {
      if (testlist[i][j] ....)
      {
         ....
         ....
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your inner loop trying to loop over? `testlist[i]` will just return a single instance of MyViewModel.

Comment: @ZippyZippedUp Think of it as a matrix of `mxn` dimension. I'm trying to loop over every entry of the list that has m rows and n columns. In my code, `I` is number of rows and `j` is number of columns. Are there any may be better workarounds?

Comment: I can't see how MyViewModel).ToList() can return you a List<MyViewModel>[][]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `testlist[i]` is an instance of `MyViewModel` class. You can't simply iterate over all it's members (properties, methods etc) with a for/foreach loop.

1) Use System.Reflection to obtain list of properties in your object (slow!)

2) Manually make array from required property values

```
var testlist = (qry to load MyViewModel)
         .Select(x => new object[] { x.ProductId, x.laborCost, x.ManufCost ...})
         .ToList();
```

Your model will be `List<object[]>` instead of `List<MyViewModel>`

3) Manually check required properties:

```
if (testlist[i].ManufCost  ....)
```

Comment: Your step 2 for using `List<object[]>` instead of `List<MyViewModel>` worked along with my Outer and Inner loops. The errors 1 and 2 of my post do not occur anymore, i.e., `testlist[i].Count();` and `testlist[i][j]` now work. Thank you for explaining your suggestion step by step - that made things easy to follow.