# Set DataType for entire column EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, powershell, epplus

**Is there a way to set the DataType for an entire column in EPPlus?**

I was previously using the LoadFromText method, which passes in an `OfficeOpenXml.ExcelTextFormat` object. One of the properties on this object being `DataTypes` set using the `OfficeOpenXml.eDataTypes` enum.

Now I'm not using the LoadFromText method to parse my data to the workbook, I can't see any other way of setting the column datatype.

**Note:** this is not the formatting, I would like to set the datatype of the column as it would be read by excel. I.E. `[OfficeOpenXml.eDataTypes]::Number`

Comment: Not quite clear what you are trying to do.  Excel/Epplus saves and load every thing as either doubles or strings.  Things like ints and datetimes are control but the Style.NumberFormat.   So you should be able to do what you want with that, no?

Comment: Right, but unfortunately I'm getting a numeric entries that are being entered as strings. This isn't something that can be changed through Style.NumberFormat

Comment: The warning in excel is "number stored as text" resulting in the green triangle at the top left of the cell

Comment: I see now. You can fix that by writing your values in epplus with proper types.  This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537981/using-epplus-how-can-i-generate-a-spreadsheet-where-numbers-are-numbers-not-text/31551083#31551083

Comment: I ended up doing something similar, but not ecstatic with that solution, as I would have thought EPPlus would have a method to set the data type for the whole column. I haven't found anything that exposes this functionality however.